# Tiny C Compiler: "error: unknown opcode 'jmp'"

Tags: c, assembly, x86, tcc

Given this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    __asm volatile ("jmp %eax");

    return 0;
}
```

32-bit TCC will complain with:

```
test.c:3: error: unknown opcode 'jmp'
```

but the 64-bit version will compile just fine.

What's the problem with the 32 bit code?

Comment: @Martin James: From [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.4): "If our assembly statement must execute where we put it, (i.e. must not be moved out of a loop as an optimization), put the keyword `volatile` after asm and before the ()’s."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to simply add a star (*) before the register, like this:

```
__asm volatile ("jmp *%eax");
```

I'm not exactly sure what the star means. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12453853/2006222) SO post:

> The star is some syntactical sugar indicating that control is to be passed indirectly, by reference/pointer.

As for why it works with 64-bit TCC, I assume that it's a bug; 64-bit GCC complains with `Error: operand type mismatch for 'jmp'`, as it should.

Comment: The `*` means it's an indirect jump, setting IP/EIP/RIP = value from register or memory, rather than `jmp rel32` to a label address.  TCC 0.9.27 still has this bug; I checked with `objdump -d` and it emits `ff e0   jmp    *%rax`